# MySQL Left Outer Join and {?}

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, left-join, mysql-workbench, qlikview

I have been tasked with converting some Crystal SQL queries into QlikView and am having trouble deciphering the SQL code as it has been a decade since I last played with this. I'm modelling the data in MySQL workbench prior to importing it into QlikView.

I have posted the code bellow for the sake of completeness although I realize a lot of it is surplus.

The issue I am having is I don't know and cant seem to work out how do duplicate these queries in MySQL workbench as I don't understand what these code segments are doing: 
`={?APS: ITEM1.ST_Prodcode}` and `={?FKE: ITEM1_1.ST_Prodcode}` etc.

The above mentioned code appears to me to be calling the next query. Am I right in thinking this?

**Pricing**

```
SELECT 
`stock_management1`.`st_prodcode`, 
`stock_management1`.`st_sdesc`, 
`stock_management1`.`st_mstockist`, 
`stock_management1`.`APS_rol`, 
`stock_management1`.`APS_eoq`, 
`stock_management1`.`APS_ms`
FROM   
`pricing`.`stock_management` 
`stock_management1`
WHERE  
(`stock_management1`.`st_mstockist`='BRA' 
OR 
`stock_management1`.`st_mstockist`='FCS' 
OR 
`stock_management1`.`st_mstockist`='FKE') 
AND 
`stock_management1`.`APS_ms`>0 
AND 
(`stock_management1`.`st_prodcode`>='A' 
AND 
`stock_management1`.`st_prodcode`<='WZZZZZ999')
EXTERNAL JOIN
stock_management1.st_prodcode={?APS: ITEM1.ST_Prodcode} 
AND 
stock_management1.st_prodcode={?FCS: stocktake1.S_ProdCode} 
AND 
stock_management1.st_prodcode={?CENTRAL: Command.mv_PRODCODE}
```

**APS**

```
SELECT `ITEM1`.`ST_SOH`, `ITEM1`.`ST_Prodcode`
FROM   `aps`.`ITEM` `ITEM1`
WHERE  `ITEM1`.`ST_Prodcode`={?pricing: stock_management1.st_prodcode}
EXTERNAL JOIN ITEM1.ST_Prodcode={?FKE: ITEM1_1.ST_Prodcode}
```

**FKE**

```
SELECT `ITEM1_1`.`ST_SOH`, `ITEM1_1`.`ST_Prodcode`
FROM   `iewkelvin`.`ITEM` `ITEM1_1`
WHERE  `ITEM1_1`.`ST_Prodcode`={?APS: ITEM1.ST_Prodcode}
EXTERNAL JOIN ITEM1_1.ST_Prodcode={?FCS: ITEM1_2.ST_Prodcode}
```

Comment: This symbol is variable for specific programming language . Its not mysql syntax

Comment: I guess these { } - segments are report parameters. You need to substitute them with a literal value or QlikView variable, for instance: '$(vPostCode)'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments imran & ralfbecher.

I found that the  `{?` implies `WHERE` followed by the Database: `table.field`

Simple as that really.